# Android: Align one button to left and second button to right in same horizontal line

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to show two buttons in a way that one button should align to the left side of the screen and the other one should align to right side of the screen in same horizontal line. `Settings` button has aligned to the left but i am not able to right align `About` button. Here is the activity xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainPageActivity"

 >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:text="@string/welcomeText"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />



<Button android:text="Find out Now!" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:background="@drawable/selectbutton" 
    style="@style/FindOutButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"/>

<Button android:text="Settings" 
    android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:background="@drawable/selectbutton" 
    style="@style/SettingsButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="204dp"/>

<Button android:text="About" 
    android:id="@+id/button3" 
    android:background="@drawable/selectbutton" 
    style="@style/AboutButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="204dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**`strings.xml:`**

```
<style name="FindOutButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>

<style name="SettingsButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>

<style name="AboutButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">2</item>
</style>
```

**selectbutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#449def" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#2f6699" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#449def"
            android:endColor="#2f6699"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#2f6699" />
        <corners
            android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Here is the output of above code:

[image]

I want to place About button to right side of the screen. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to the about button

Comment: This will cause an "overlapping items in RelativeLayout" warning

Answer (score 2):

Give the `About` button the attribute `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`, to make it align on the right margin, and the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to make it stay at that bottom, finally remove the `android:layout_toRightOf="@id..."`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <ImageView           
        android:id="@+id/wifiStatusImage"
        android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"     
        android:layout_marginLeft ="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:src = "@drawable/WifiOn" />

         <ImageView           
        android:id="@+id/SearchP2PDevices"       
        android:layout_marginTop ="0dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight ="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:src = "@drawable/search"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have two image views instead of button. Note that android:layout_alignParentRight="true" & android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" will do the work.